# How to remove a class name from the MarionetteCollectionview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marionette

i have defined a collection view like the following

```
HexGridNonEditableCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
                itemView : HexGridNonEditableItemView,
                tagName : 'tr',
                className : 'hexgrid-view'
            });
```

I use this collection view in some other layout by creating instance for the above collectionview

now i want to add or remove the className which is specified in the collectionview in the Layout where i create instance for the CollectionView.

how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The className needs to be set even before the `initialize` method is called so unfortunately there is no way that you can influence the class after the view has been created

One solution is to modify the `$el` attribute in `onRender` (or anywhere else for that matter)

I would recommend setting the className when you create the view. So although you can't influence the view after its been created, you can at least reuse the component

```
var view = new HexGridNonEditableCollectionView({
   collection: someCollection,
   className: 'hexgrid-view2'
});
```

Just change that className property of the constructor parameter and you should be good to go